# How can I create a php menu from a directory?

Tags: php, css, recursion, menu

I need to create a php menu from a directory, i have this folder: Publications.
And i want to list the items inside as a dynamic menu. 
The items look like this: 
**newsletter_2013_1.pdf
newsletter_2013_2.pdf
newsletter_2014_1.pdf
newsletter_2014_2.pdf**

And the menu that i need to create has to be something like this:
**Please choose a year: -> 2013 -> Issue# 1 / Issue# 2 / Issue # 3**

I'll appreciate any help I can get thanks!

**UPDATE**
So far i have this code:

```
$paths = new DirectoryIterator('/usr/apps/webdata/backend/assets/newsletters/temp');

echo '<div id=cssmenu>';
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li class=has-sub last><a href=#><span>Please select a Year</span></a>';
echo '<ul>';
$list = array();
foreach($paths as $file)
{
if($file->isDot())
    continue;
    $string = $file;

                if(preg_match_all("#(\d{1,})#", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) 
                {
                        foreach($matches as $match) 
                        {

                        $issue = $match[0];

                            while (list($key, $value) = each($match)) 
                            {
                            //YEAR
                                if (strlen ($value) == 4)
                                {
                                $uyear = $value;
                                //echo "Year: $uyear \n";
                                //echo "<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>".$uyear." </span></a>";

                                }
                            // ISSUE#
                                elseif (strlen ($value) == 1)
                                {
                                $uissue = $value;
                                //echo "Issue: $uissue \n";
                                //echo "<li class=last><a href=# onclick=myPDF('".$file."')> Issue# ".$uissue."</a></li>";
                                }

                            }

                    }
}   

if(!isset($list[$uyear]))
{
        $list[$uyear] = array();
    echo "<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>".$uyear." </span></a>";
}   
echo '<ul>';
if(!in_array($uissue, $list[$uyear]))
{
    $list[$uyear][] = $uissue;

    //for($i=0;$i<4; $i++)
        //{
        echo "<li class=last><a href=# onclick=myPDF('".$file."')> Issue# ".$uissue."</a></li>";
        //echo '<h2 style= margin-top: 20px;>Preview Issue# '.$uissue.' from '.$uyear.' </h2>';
        //}         
}

echo '</ul>';
echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
```

But it doesn't work the way i need it

**UPDATE 2**
I was able to create my menu, but now for every Issue# keeps creating a new branch on my tree, and I want to have all the issues under the same number

Comment: What have your tried?  Please post your code.

Comment: I tried that approach already, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PHP Glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to grab files from a directory.  Then use foreach to echo out a set of links...

I've used it to dynamically load images into a gallery.

```
<?php
    $counter = 0; // Set counter to 0
    foreach (glob("images/photo-strip/thumb/*.jpg") as $pathToThumb) { // Grab files from the thumbnail path and save them to variable
        $th_filename = basename($pathToThumb); // Strip the thumbnail filename from the path
        $filename = str_replace('th_', '', $th_filename); // Strip th_ from the filename and save it to a different variable
        $pathToFull = 'images/photo-strip/' . $filename; // Rebuild the path to the full-size image
        echo ("<section class=\"photo-box\"><a href=\"$pathToFull\"><img src=\"$pathToThumb\" /></a></section>"); // Echo the photobox
        $counter++; // Increment counter by 1 until no file exists
    }
?>
```

Yours would be something like...

```
foreach (glob("path/2012/*.html") as $pathTo2012) {
    $filename = basename($pathTo2012);
    echo "<a href=\"$pathTo2012\">$filename</a>";
```

**In reply to your edit:**

```
<?php

$dir = "directory/";

$year = "2009";

echo "<ul>";


foreach ($year as $label ) {
    if (($year >= 2009) && ($year <= date(Y))) {
        echo "<li>$label";
        echo buildLinks;
        echo "</li>";
    }   
}

$year++; //increment year by 1


function buildLinks () {

    echo "<ul>";

    foreach (glob($dir . $year . "/*.html") as $filepath) {

        $filename = basename($filepath);

        echo "<li><a href=\"$filepath\">$filename</a></li>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}

echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Note this is untested and not tailored perfectly to your situation.  Some modification will probably be needed.  Unfortunately I'm not in a situation to test PHP at the present moment.

Comment: I like your approach, but how can I have this on a menu like... showing the year first, and inside that all the childs which are the issues?

Comment: It would depend on how dynamic you need the year display to be.  I would wrap it all in nested UL's.  So UL's for the years and inside the li's for the years do a UL for the actual links.

Do some sort of IF-ELSE statement that says If year = 2012 is true then foreach the code above.  Else if year = 2013 is true than foreach the code above to a different filepath.  See my edit

Comment: Yes, i create this array but is just printing the last Year & last issue: if(!isset($menu[$uyear])) 
      {
         $menu[$uyear] = array();
      }
    // Add the issue
      $menu[$uyear][] = $uissue;

Comment: Sorry it took me a minute, look now

Comment: Thanks Michael, with your help I was able to find the problem and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an overkill, but I hope it helps:

```
if(!is_readable($DirName)) { # Make sure the dir is readable before going on
    printf("You do not have permission to read:") ;
    printf("<blockquote><code>\n%s\n</code></blockquote>",$DirName) ;
}
else if(!is_dir($DirName)) { # Make sure it is a directory
    printf("The requested item is not a directory:") ;
    printf("<blockquote><code>\n%s\n</code></blockquote>",$DirName) ;
}
else if(($FileList = scandir($DirName))==FALSE) { # Are we able to scan the directory
    printf("<h2>Cannot get listing</h2>\n") ;
    printf("Cannot get list of the contents of the directory:") ;
    printf("<blockquote><code>\n%s\n</code></blockquote>",$DirName) ;
}
else { 
    $FileCount = sizeof($FileList) ;
    printf("Current working directory is:<blockquote><pre>%s</pre></blockquote>\n",posix_getcwd()) ;
    printf("Searching <blockquote><pre>%s</pre></blockquote>\n",$DirName) ;
    printf("<ul>\n") ;
    for($Count=0;$Count<$FileCount && $Count<$CountLimit;$Count++) {
        printf("<li>%s</li>\n",$FileList[$Count]) ;
    }

     # The number of files shown was limited by $CountLimit, if there are more files beyond what was shown above then show how many
    $Difference = $FileCount-$CountLimit ;
    if($Difference>0)
        printf("<li><i>&hellip;%d more file%s/director%s</i></li>",$Difference,$Difference==1?"":"s",$Difference==1?"y":"ies") ;
    printf("</ul>\n") ;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after I found the problem, I was able to generate a CSS Menu with my values inside, here's the final code:

```
    echo '<div id=cssmenu>';
// This If is to check that the array is not empty  
    if(count($menu) > 0) {      

    echo '<ul>';    
        echo '   <li class=has-sub last><a href=#><span>Please Select a Year:</span></a>';
        echo '   <ul>';
                    foreach($menu as $uyear => $docs) 
                    {
                    echo "<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>".$uyear." </span></a>";
                    echo '            <ul>';

                    foreach($docs as $filename) 
                    {
                    $a= "Newsletter_$uyear";
                    $b="_$filename.pdf";
                    $myissue = $a.$b;
                    echo "<li class=last><a href=# onclick=myPDF('".$myissue."')> Issue# ".$filename."</a></li>";
                    }
        echo '            </ul>';
        echo '         </li>';
                    }
        echo '   </ul>';
        echo '   </li>';

    echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
```